# Is a recursive async function better or faster than a function that uses await?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, async-await

In TypeScript I wrote a function that returns all directories or files of a given path. I started using a recursive async approach and this works absolutely fine.

At the same time, it looks more difficult to read. Is there any side-effect or disadvantage to switch to an `await` implementation in terms of blocking? Here is the function prototype:

Disclaimer: I am new to async programming

```
function walkHierarchy(path: string): string[];
```

And here is my current implementation:

```js
export async function walkHierarchy(dirPath: string): Promise<string[]> {
    if (dirPath.endsWith('/')) {
      dirPath = dirPath.substring(0, dirPath.length - 1);
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fse.readdir(dirPath, (err: NodeJS.ErrnoException, entries: string[]) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          const items = [];
          const promises = [];
  
          for (const entry of entries) {
              const absPath = `${dirPath}${path.sep}${entry}`;
  
              items.push(absPath);
              promises.push(walkHierarchy(absPath));
            }
          }
  
          Promise.all(promises).then((d) => {
            resolve(items.concat(...d));
          }).catch((error) => resolve(error));
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Side note on your current implementation: There's no reason for your function to be declared `async` if you never use `await` in it. I'd probably use the [promise-enabled version of `readdir`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readdir_path_options) instead so you don't have to explicitly create a promise.

Comment: Thanks! Doesn't it need to be async because of the Promise I return?

Comment: P.S. I am wondering that `fs-extra` exists and `fsPromises`

Comment: No. Any function can return a promise. An `async` function **always** returns a promise, one that it creates implicitly. Your function above is returning a promise that is resolved to the promise you're returning. There's no need for that extra level. (FWIW, I go into promises and `async` functions in some detail in my new book, *JavaScript: The New Toys* in Chapters 8 and 9. Links in my profile if you're interested.)

Comment: That's awesome, thank you a lot! I will definitely take a look at this.